# ns3 mobile node declaration

Tags: mobile, wifi, simulation, declare

I'm in need of creating mobile device node to communicate between nodes using wifi for sharing files need to be simulated using ns3. Can help me with the code

1. Declaration and creation of mobile device node.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of scenarios with wireless nodes in [/examples/wireless](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/dir_2ed9fc3d4c8eeb99a1460aa5faee4b2e.html)

Most of them use simple applications to send constant traffic (dummy packets).
You can use the [BulkSend](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__bulksend.html) application in NS-3 to send (over TCP) a file of certain size.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.
In the above question mobile node i would like to mean is cellular node.
And also the data packet need to be send using UDP packet, not using using TCP packet.

Comment: @suuz If you wanted a cellular why did you say "using wifi"? For cellular nodes (LTE in particular) there are examples in /src/lte/examples In these examples, there are applications using UDP or TCP.

Comment: my projects is regarding adhoc network in cellular mobile phone.with this combination can you please provide a solution.

Comment: Current LTE implementation in NS-3 does not support ad-hoc mode (I guess you are referring to Device-to-Device communication).